# Python apyori seems to be miscalculating support and lift

Tags: python, apriori

Python's apyori package seems to be miscalculating lift and support.

I created the following example

```
rules=[['apples', 'oranges'],
       ['apples'],
       ['apples'],
       ['sugar'],
       ['apples', 'oranges'],
       ['sugar','apples'],
       ['bananas'],
      ['bananas'],
      ['bananas'],
      ['bananas']]
```

I then run the apriori by running

```
from apyori import apriori
association_rules = apriori(rules, min_support=.0001, min_confidence=0, min_lift=0, min_length=0)
association_results = list(association_rules)
print(association_results)
```

The results should be:

```
Confidence of apples to oranges = (Transactions containing both (apple and orange))/(Transactions containing apple) = 2/4 = .5
```

However the output I am getting is

```
RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'apples', 'oranges'}), support=0.2, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset(), items_add=frozenset({'apples', 'oranges'}), confidence=0.2, lift=1.0)
```

so confidence is .2

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but this is the same for all examples Confidence and support are always exactly the same as well, so the lift is always 1.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @AMC the code given is an MRE.

Comment: @ialarmedalien That wasn't the case when I wrote my comment.

Comment: i mean the confidence of {} => {apples, oranges} is 0.2 right?, that is what the ordered statistics is telling you or?  (There should be additional ordered statistics for other association rules, or are there not?)

Comment: @Feelx234 If there are four total orders with apple and two of them have oranges, isn't confidence .5 (rather than .2)?

Comment: @ramen_noodles you assume that the association rule is {apples}=>{oranges} which it is not the rule you look at!!! The rule you have here is  {} => {apples, oranges}. So the rule is 'nothing' implies apples and oranges which has confidence of 0.2.
In the ordered Statistics object `items_base`  describes the antecendent (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antecedent_(logic)) and `items_add` {apples, oranges} is the consequence.

Comment: @Feelx234 You're right, sorry about that.   I was actually thinking of confidence.  Shouldn't that be .5?